# Is it possible to replace the thermal sensor of my case?

Tags: hardware-failure, sensors

During the update of my computer hardware, I managed to damage one of the thermal sensors which my case has, making the display LCD show a "Er" (Error) on the LCD screen which monitor the temperatures of the case. My question is, with a replacement of the damaged sensor and a little bit of soldering, do you think I will have no problem repairing it? do you know how are these things called specifically, or where I can buy them online?

[image: the 3 thermal sensors of my case]

The mentioned sensors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can go about doing this.

The first would be to actually repair the faulty one,

[This](http://www.instructables.com/id/Fix-broken-temperature-sensors-in-your-PC-case/) link shows you how to do that while **[this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/250?)** one found on the same page, tells you where you can find thermistors.

[image: thermistors]

The second way to go about this is to just buy new ones, also available at the link above, or you can head over to [frozencpu.com](http://www.frozencpu.com/cat/l2/g34/c137/list/p1/Bay_Devices-Temperature_Monitors.html) and maybe find a solution that is actually better suited for your situation such as this  [Innovatek HD-O-Matic MICRO II Temperature Sensor](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/2003/ex-blc-211/Innovatek_HD-O-Matic_MICRO_II_Temperature_Sensor_500955.html?tl=g34c137)

[image: 3-Pin Sensor]

The third is to just use the sensors that your hardware has inbuilt, since those are obviously more accurate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was exactly looking for a "DIY" type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more hassle to fix the sensors than relying on the CPU/Motherboard internal sensors and coping with the error message.

For example: even if you find a compatible sensor at [digikey.com](http://digikey.com) or some other electronic components store, for example, a NTC sensor of a certain resistance and certain accuracy, you may need to calibrate it to see a believable temperature on the display.

Also, there are computer LCD modules with temperature sensors and fan controllers, that you could add to your system instead of the broken one. 
Such as: [NZXT Sentry-2 5.25" Touch Screen Fan Controller](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811992005)